# Comment deletion notifications

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, deleted-posts

I see that all the comments I made to the questions referenced in [Wordreference cross-posting](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/wordreference-cross-posting) have been deleted. Can I somehow be notified when my comments are deleted?

Comment: I was also wondering whether I can be notified when my comments have been deleted, or even responded to.