# Why were my comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, deleted-posts

All the comments I made under the questions referenced in [Wordreference cross-posting](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/wordreference-cross-posting) have been deleted. Why?

Comment: Did you leave similar comments for all the questions?

Comment: All the comments were pointing to a question asked on WR, aren't they?

Comment: Well, once you pointed out on the post here on this meta that the user keeps asking questions on Stack Exchange, and on another forum, it doesn't make sense to keep the comments pointing out which questions have been already asked on that forum.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I disagree. Not only are the links useful to my meta post (which is _still_ open and not acted upon), they are also useful for existing close votes, and for directing users to another source for answers to the same copied and pasted question.

Comment: Most of the users who vote to close read the questions on the meta site. I have myself voted to close those questions after I read your previous question. Since there is nothing wrong with asking the same question on a forum, and on a Stack Exchange site, there isn't any need to point out the question asked on that forum.

Comment: You posted the comment several times, and they got flagged. They didn't help the individual questions, so they were deleted

Comment: @simchona Please see my comment above and address each of the points. Note that the comments were not identical.